# Why wont rigid body work on my conveyor belt?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I've tried to follow tutorials on just conveyor belts and rigid body but sadly for the most part it falls through or has instances of the object pinging off or somewhat staying on.

[Blender file](https://mega.nz/folder/heIkhSRB#jgOdIYMtYtt2y8OCuxMj4A)}
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Set the origin of the belt to its geometry

Comment: Hi Senress - i don't wanna disappoint you, but my experience in the last year was: i don't know what happened with rigid body simulations + conveyor belts, but the tutorials worked 1,5-2 years ago when i started with Blender. Unfortunately in the meantime the rigid body simulation in that area (animating array + curve) has gone very very unstable and often not workable anymore. In former times you could make it work with "not applied" array modifier - and it worked great. Some month ago the solution seemed to be to apply the array modifier, then it worked (but was already pretty unstable)...

Comment: ...and now i cannot make this work too. Maybe filing a bug report for this is a good idea. I just tried it with 2 different blender versions....and both crashed several times. :(

Comment: in my opinion one of the biggest problems is the geometry of your belt. You gave your array object a bevel modifier (or bevelled it manually) -> by this the geometry is pretty complicated for the rigid body system to calculate. Maybe try building just "simple" cubes (which you just scale) as array and try again. Use them as rigid body object. You can hide them later and use your "nice" belt to render (but of course without rigid body).